# Swapping order of distribution and integration

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

> For $\phi$ a smooth compactly supported function on $\mathbb R^m\times\mathbb R^n$,
> let $\phi_y=\phi(\cdot,y)$. Let $f$ be a
> distribution on $\mathbb R^m$.  Show that if $\psi(y)=f(\phi_y)$, then
> $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\psi(y)\;dy=f(\Phi),$$ where
> $\Phi(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\phi(x,y)\;dy$.

This looks like some version of the Fubini theorem, as we are exchanging the order of integration over $\mathbb R^n$ with applying the linear functional $f$. In fact, it is basically exactly the statement of Fubini in the case that $f$ is the distribution arising from some locally integrable function.

I am not sure about when $f$ is a general distribution though. I know that the map $\psi$ is smooth, but I'm not sure how this might help.

Comment: Use `\cdot` for $\cdot$, not `\bullet`.

Comment: Yes, this is Fubini. It holds when $$f(\phi) = \int \phi w, $$ where $w$ is a smooth function. Now approximate an arbitrary distribution by one like this and take a limit.

Comment: Let $f_t$ be a smooth family of distributions of the form I gave such that their weak limit as $t\rightarrow 0$ is the original distribution $f$.

Comment: @Deane how might a general distribution $f$ be approximated by those that are equivalent to integrating against some $w$?

Comment: 99\% of all facts about distributions can be proved this way. Approximate by a smooth function and take a weak limit.

Comment: @ruppel convolve it with a smooth bump function at some scale $\varepsilon$ which you then send to $0$.

Comment: What are you using to learn about distributions? This should be described in any introduction to distributions.

Comment: For Fubini's theorem for distributions see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free/351028#351028